# Clearing history: Squashing A to B and D to E commits in Git

Tags: git, version-control, git-rebase

I have an ugly history on my repo and I want to streamline-it a little bit. From what I've read, git rebase would be the tool I should use. What I want to do is:

Turn this:

```
A--------------------------I (master)
 \                        /
  B--C-------------G--H--/ (development)
      \           /
       D--E------/ (feature-1)
           \    /
            F--/ (feature-2)
```

Into this:

```
A-BCDEFH--I (master)
```

After the commit "I", I have other commits in the same form, so I would like my final history to look like:

```
A-BCDEFH--I--KLMNO-P (master)
```

Any pointers in how to accomplish this?

EDIT: Please note that in this example, D and F are not merge commits - they are standard commits, so none of them should dissapear from the history (although the merge commits, G and I should).

Comment: Are you intentionally leaving out G from your final history?

Comment: `G` is a merge commit, so it has no real history when the history is linearized.  (For that matter, so is `I`... it will go away in a rebase too.)

Comment: In this example, I am leaving out the merge commits. So D and F are "actual" commits. I apologize for the confusion - edited.

Comment: According to this history, A, B, C, D, E, F, and H are all actual commits -- G and I are merges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish the first step with this:

```
$ git checkout -b new-master master
$ git rebase --onto A A new-master
```

Where `A` is the commit identifier for the A commit in your graph.

This will create a new branch `new-master` that will ultimately wind up in the shape you want `master` in (merge commits that introduce no changes of their own will be dropped from the history).  To port over the other branches, check them out one-by-one and issue `git rebase --onto new-master master branchname`.

When you are satisfied with the changes, you can update the `master` branch and delete `new-master`:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git reset --hard new-master
$ git branch -d new-master
```

Comment: I believe you want `new-master` as the last argument to your first `rebase` command.

Comment: @cdhowie In this example, you say "git rebase --onto A **A** new-master" - is this the range of commits that I want to rebase? Or just "A new-master"?

Comment: `A new-master` means "take all of the commits reachable from `new-master`, excluding `A` and its ancestors."  `--onto A` means "build the new commits on top of commit `A`".  So you put it all together as "take all of the commits reachable from `new-master`, excluding `A` and its ancestors, and rebuild them on top of `A`."

Comment: @cdhowie This does streamline the history, yet it **recreates** the commits, as if I just made them (meaning that they will be in the top of the timeline, which is false, and it doesn't conserve the date and time). Notice that in the question, I want A-BCDEFH--I - this means that I want just a group of commits streamlined, and the rest of them, untouched. Any thoughts? I start to think that it isn't possible.

Comment: Of course it recreates them.  Modifying any aspect of a commit will change its identity, as the commit identity is a cryptographic hash of the commit contents.  It's impossible to simply modify a commit.  Now, the behavior you are seeing is correct: Git is rewriting the commits, preserving the *authorship* date, but resetting the *commit* date.  Use `git log --pretty=full` to see both dates.

Comment: @cdhowie Amazing - didn't knew that that was the only behavior available in Git, so it answers my question. Thank you for the tips!